# When setting navigation graph programmatically after recreating activity, wrong fragment is shown

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am setting a navigation graph programmatically to set the start destination depending on some condition (for example, active session), but when I tested this with the "Don't keep activities" option enabled I faced the following bug.

When activity is just recreated and the app calls method NavController.setGraph, NavController forces restoring the Navigation back stack (from internal field mBackStackToRestore in onGraphCreated method) even if start destination is different than before so the user sees the wrong fragment.

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var navController: NavController
    lateinit var navHost: NavHostFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        log("fresh start = ${savedInstanceState == null}")
        navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_nav_host) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHost.navController
        createGraph(App.instance.getValue())
    }

    private fun createGraph(bool: Boolean) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Is session active: $bool", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        log("one: ${R.id.fragment_one}, two: ${R.id.fragment_two}")
        val graph =
            if (bool) {
                log("fragment one")
                navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph).also {
                    it.startDestination = R.id.fragment_one
                }
            } else {
                log("fragment two")
                navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph).also {
                    it.startDestination = R.id.fragment_two
                }
            }
        navController.setGraph(graph, null)
    }
}
```

App code:

```
class App : Application() {
    companion object {
        lateinit var instance: App
    }

    private var someValue = true
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    fun getValue(): Boolean {
        val result = someValue
        someValue = !someValue
        return result
    }
}
```

Fragment One and Two are just empty fragments.

How it looks like:
[image]

Repository with full code and more explanation available by [link](https://github.com/HreshchyshynT/NavigationBug)

My question: is it a Navigation library bug or I am doing something wrong? Maybe I am using a bad approach and there is a better one to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is some wrong behaviour in the library and my approach wasn't 100% correct too. At least, there is the better one and it works well.
Because I am using the same graph and only changing the start destination, I can simply set that graph in onCreate of my activity and set some default start destination there. Then, in `createGraph` method, I can do the following:

```
    // pop backStack while it is not empty
    while (navController.currentBackStackEntry != null) {
        navController.popBackStack()
    }
    // then just navigate to desired destination with additional arguments if needed
    navController.navigate(destinationId, destinationBundle)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you tried in your repository, It comes from save/restoreInstanceState.

It means you set suit graph in `onCreate` via `createGraph(App.instance.getValue())` and then fragmentManager in `onRestoreInstanceState` will override your configuration for NavHostFragment.

So you can set another another time the graph in `onRestoreInstanceState`. But it will not work because of [this line](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-navigation-release:navigation/navigation-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/NavController.java;l=633;drc=698a009fa89a2a8d1b1cd3403a52bae58501052d) and backstack is not empty. (I think this behavior may be a bug...)

Because of you're using a graph `(R.navigation.nav_graph)` for different situation and just change their `startDestination`, you can be sure after process death, used graph is your demand graph. So just override `startDestination` in `onRestoreInstanceState`.

```
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)

    if (codition) {
        navController.graph.startDestination = R.id.fragment_one
    } else {
        navController.graph.startDestination = R.id.fragment_two
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I tried to set the start destination in onRestoreInstanceState, I received an exception. The problem is that after recreating the activity, the nav graph is not recreated, but fragments are. Also, changing of start destination without recreating the graph doesn't have any effect :(